# Taylor series coefficient calculation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Let $f,\phi$ be two functions holomorphic on the open simply connected $\Omega$ with $0\in\Omega, \phi$ not identicaly $0$ with $f(z)=\phi(z)h(z)$, $h$ holomorphic in $\Omega$ and $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}\int_0^z\frac{f(j)}{\phi(j)}dj$. 
>  1) Prove that $g$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$ and 
>  2) Calculate the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of $g$ as a function of the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of $f$ and the Laurent coefficients of $\phi$ around $0$.

I proved that $g$ is holomorphic by Morera's Theorem. Let $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n, f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ and $1/\phi(z)=\sum_{n=-N}^{\infty}\gamma_nz^n$ then I have $(zg(z))'=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)b_nz^n=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz_n)(\sum_{n=-N}^{\infty}\gamma_nz^n)$. Taking the positive and negative exponents separately: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)b_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\gamma_{n-k})z^n+(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz_n)(\sum_{n=-N}^{-1}\gamma_nz^n)$.

So my question is: how can I find the coefficients of this sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\gamma_{n-k})z^n+(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz_n)(\sum_{n=-N}^{-1}\gamma_nz^n)$ ?

Comment: the idea is that $(zg'+g)\phi=f$ gives you a recurrence; note though that $g$ holomorphic requires $f/\phi$ not to have zeroes on $\Omega$ so I think you need $\phi(z) \ne 0,z \in \Omega$

Comment: @Conrad Yes I had a really serious assumption I forgot to add, that $f/\phi$ is holomorphic!

Comment: the recurrence works then too since $f,\phi$ have the same order of zero at zero

Comment: But that way I will get a recurrence $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)b_k\gamma_{n-k}$ which I am not sure how to solve, also I was asked to calculate this using the Laurent coefficients of $1/\phi$

Comment: the recurrence above is easily solvable by induction; if you want to use the Laurent coefficients of $1/\phi$ note that if $\phi(0)=0$ and the order is $k \ge 1$ then also $f(0)=0$ has order at least $k$, so $f$ starts at $z^k$ and there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: Ah ok I will check straight away!